# Were the three Star Wars prequels intended?

Tags: star-wars

After the making of *Episodes IV*, *V*, and *VI* of *Star Wars*, was it immediately decided to make the three prequels, or was it due to some other factors (e.g., financial)?

Comment: I wouldn't impute financial reasons to Lucas, but I doubt him to have planned these since the original movies. But well, I don't know.

Comment: I remember hearing that he had wanted to have Yoda fight (like in Episode 2) but it couldn't be done with the technology at the time.
Also, around the time of episode 1-3 there was at least 1 (magazine, I think?) interview where Lucas said he originally planned a series of 9 episodes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

George Lucas had the basic outlines for the prequels written, including many characters and settings, even as *Return of the Jedi* was wrapping.

However, he lost his enthusiasm to continue the series in 1987 following a financially damaging divorce, and turned his attention to other endeavors - the culmination of which would be THX sound, Pixar, advancements in video gaming and pushing the cinematic boundaries through ILM. Eventually though, the Star Wars saga began to gain momentum again due to the comics produced by Dark Horse and the novels written by Timothy Zahn, and when he saw the results of his company's CGI effects in films such as *Terminator 2* and *Jurassic Park*, he realized the technology was available for him to realize his original vision. Also, Lucas could see that the fan-base was growing, rather than dwindling, and as an independent company, Lucasfilm needed to generate its own income in order to finance other projects, and a new *Star Wars* film (and associated merchandising) would certainly fill the coffers.

He began writing the script for Episode 1 in 1994 (putting a long-gestating project, *Red Tails*, on hold) and made the focus of the saga the story of Anakin Skywalker which encompassed the classic theme of the rise, fall and redemption of a hero. It is noteworthy that many of the character names and settings from the prequels can be found in the very earliest drafts of the original Star Wars.

Comment: It's several different sources condensed into one answer, but I would be happy to provide the links if you need them.

Comment: Thanks, but not necessary -- I tried to remove my down-vote (unsuccessfully) after re-reading your answer. I mistakenly thought you were saying Lucas had begun working on the prequels before he made Star Wars, which strikes me as unbelievable. But you answered that Lucas began working on prequels some time around Return of the Jedi production, which is easy to accept.

Comment: No worries - I probably deserved that down-vote as I did indeed forget to add my sources :)

Comment: @ShaneFinneran Feel free to just make a small dummy-edit in order to remove your downvote (which is always possible when the question has changed).

Answer (score 3):

*Episode IV* was not in opening of the original release of *Star Wars* (1977), it was added for the re-release a few years later. This is one of those we will never know type questions. Lucas has made many claims and who knows what the real story is.

He broke movie making rules when he made this movie, got kicked out of the directors guild if I understand it right. Changed the world from a lot of unhappy ending movies to the heroes win at the end with a happy ending.  My guess is he was probably happy to have had at least had this project at all. If it failed who cares if there were other stories, if it succeeded then use the money and success to make more movies. From star wars to Jedi, the little furry animals were supposed to be Wookiees, but that would make Chewbacca an also-ran not a special character, and other reasons the story was changed. How much time was there from Star Wars to Jedi and from Jedi to episode 1? The better question might be how many hundreds of versions of these stories were there before settling in on the 6 we have?  There  were supposed to be 9, three prequels and three sequels after this set, where are the other three, why waste time messing up Star Wars every so many years and just finish the series?

The problem with a prequel or set of them in this case, especially with a cult classic like star wars, you have to get all the facts right, you have to create Darth Vader, the Empire, Luke and Leia and so on. Episode III is 100% checklist, nothing else, kids born, check, kids distributed, check, create Vader, check, Empire in place, check, etc etc.

The bottom line the Episode IV tag was not part of the original, it was added after the original was a huge success, big enough to have a re-release (this was before VCRs and cable TV with movie channels), we will never know.

Comment: I guess we will just have to disagree on that.  I have seen both, a number of folks on the net confirm this, etc, etc.

Comment: I guess we will :-)  ... I would be interested in seeing any links you have on that.  Memory *is* a funny thing, but I saw Star Wars in 1977 and do think I saw that directly and not on a subsequent re-release.  I just had a brief look and can't find a reference that says it did not have Episode IV in the opening text.

Comment: from imdb.  Upon its original release, the opening crawl did not include "Episode IV: A New Hope." According to Lucasfilm, this was added upon its re-release in 1981. The later print was the first one to be released on mass market video (an earlier Betamax release did not have the subtitle), and all video, laserdisc or DVD releases have featured the subtitles. The theatrical cut DVDs, released in September 2006, were the first time that the original opening crawl, without subtitle, has been released on home video.

Comment: I have the two laserdisc sets and a number of dvd sets, will see if I have the 2006 version.  And will see if my laserdisc players still work.

Comment: There is every chance I am 'remembering' the 1981 release which I had on VHS.  I stand corrected and withdraw my answer.

Comment: The 2006 dvd has the 1977 release on disk 2, There is no Episode IV and no A New Hope after STAR WARS and before the text of the crawl.